# GET REQUEST not returning student grade properly

Tags: java, mysql

On all the **subjects** of the student the same **grade** is retrieved, the grade of the **first** subject is repeated in the other subject grades. I know the problem is in the hashmap that I have defined for subjects so what changes do I need to do there for this problem to be fixed.

**Here is what it looks like:**

[image]

Here is the method that the **GET REQUEST** calls:

```
  public Student getStudentById(int id) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;

        Student student = new Student();


        student.setSubjectList(new ArrayList<>());


        Map<String,Subject> subjectMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,StudentMark> markMap = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            connection = new MysqlDbConnectionService().getConnection();


            String select = "SELECT s.user_id, s.username, s.password,  s.fullname,  s.email,subj.id, subj.name, f.fid, f.university_id," +
                    " f.fname,p.professor_id, p.first_name,p.last_name,p.title, g.grade_id, g.mark, g.description " +
                    " FROM student s " +
                    "         INNER JOIN student_faculty sf ON sf.student_id=s.user_id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN faculty f ON sf.faculty_id=f.fid\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN faculty_subject fs ON f.fid = fs.faculty_id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN subject subj ON fs.subject_id = subj.id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN professor_subject ps ON ps.subject_id = subj.id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN professor p ON ps.prof_id = p.professor_id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN student_subject_marks sm ON sm.student_id = s.user_id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN student_subject_marks ds ON ds.subject_id = subj.id\n" +
                    "         INNER JOIN grade g ON sm.grade_id = g.grade_id\n" +
                    "WHERE user_id = ?";

            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(select);
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


            while (rs.next()) {

                if(student.getId()==null) {

                    student.setId(rs.getString("user_id"));
                    student.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                    student.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                    student.setFullName(rs.getString("fullname"));
                    student.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                }

                String subjectID=rs.getString("id");

                Subject subject =null;
                Professor professor=null;
                StudentMark mark = null;

                if(!subjectMap.containsKey(subjectID)) {
                   subject=new Subject();
                    subject.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                    subject.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                    subject.setProfessorList(new ArrayList<>());
                    subject.setMarkList(new ArrayList<>());
                    subjectMap.put(subjectID, subject);

                    professor = new Professor();
                    professor.setProfessor_id(rs.getInt("professor_id"));
                    professor.setFirst_name(rs.getString("first_name"));
                    professor.setLast_name(rs.getString("last_name"));
                    professor.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));

                    mark = new StudentMark();
                    mark.setGrade_id(rs.getInt("grade_id"));
                    mark.setMark(rs.getInt("mark"));
                    mark.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

                    subject.getProfessorList().add(professor);
                    subject.getMarkList().add(mark);

                }
                else{
                    subject = subjectMap.get(subjectID);
                }
//


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e + "Retrieve not successful");

        }
        student.getSubjectList().addAll(subjectMap.values());


        return student;



    }
```

Here is the **ER DIAGRAM:**

[image]

Comment: Is the problem necessarily in your HashMap? If you take Java out of the picture for the moment and run your SQL query in a database tool such as MySQL Workbench, does it return the correct results?

Comment: I think the problem is after if(!subjectMap.containsKey(subjectID))  because it starts getting the grades but doesn't continue mapping them after it gets the first grade and it puts the first grade it gets on all the other subjects, so yes I think the problem is java.

Comment: So have you done as I suggested and run your SQL query in a tool such as MySQL Workbench? Sometimes we might think we know where the problem in a piece of code is but it turns out the problem is somewhere else that we've overlooked. Look at the data returned by your SQL query. If it's all good, then we know the problem isn't with your query. If your SQL query is returning the wrong data, then your Java code will also return the wrong data. In fact, looking at your query, why are you joining on `student_subject_marks` twice?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it otherwise.